# Can i get list of users associated with a content in CMIS?

Tags: alfresco, acl, cmis

I am trying to implement a user-content ACL mapping service in alfresco using CMIS where I will allow a user to see a content if he is having permissions for this content.

I have get list of ACE for a content using CMIS ACL service but I am still trying to find out a way where I can get to know if a user has permissions on this content or he belongs to any of ACEs of this content. Or there are some common ACLs/ACEs between content and user which I can match before I can allow/deny access for content.

As CMIS is repository agnostic standard, I hope if I can get something to complete the mapping service.

Comment: I am not sure about your use case. You want to display the content if the user has permission to it, that is my understanding. Why do you need to implement a mapping service for this? The CMIS repository should already filter out any content the user is not allowed to see when using navigation / query services.

Comment: I am indexing alfresco content into solr. Here i also want to store content ACL with content itself. Now when a user is coming to search in solr, i want to make sure that he must get only those results for which he is eligible. So i want to compare his permissions with those attached to content in solr. If he is in any of groups in ACE attached to content, he should see the results otherwise not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using CMIS 1.1 against Alfresco, you could try using the ACE principal ID to retrieve the corresponding person / group. This is possible through the introduction of the cmis:item base type in CMIS 1.1. See http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/04/28/3703 for information about those possibilities.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to resolve user-group or group-group memberships as those relations are child associations which Alfresco does not exposes as a CMIS relationship.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because the standard does not care about a principal's effective rights on a documentary database object.

And I needed exactly the same thing, but I had to give up.